# How do I exclude an imported list of directories from a Get-ChildItem list?

Tags: powershell

Our online backup software is skipping files and directories when uploading. It seems random, but I'd like to see if I can compare a list of files in the selection to the list of files in the cloud to look for a pattern.

The items in the cloud are available in a .csv, but I'm having difficulty generating a list of files in the backup selection while excluding other directories. Here's what I have so far.

```
$colSelection = get-content "c:\scripts\selection.txt"
$colExclusion = get-content "c:\scripts\exclusion.txt"
foreach ($folder in $colSelection) {
            $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $folder -recurse -force | where-object {(-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.FullName -notlike $colExclusion)})
            foreach ($item in $colItems) {
                Add-Content -Path c:\scripts\testlist.txt -Value $item.FullName
            }
        }
```

The .txt files are lists of directories. The best way to do this seems to be to use regex, but I don't know that I can dynamically create the expression from a .txt file.

Comment: You might be able to get away with something like `$colExclusion = "($((get-content "c:\scripts\exclusion.txt") -join '|' ))"` and then `($_.FullName -notmatch $colExclusion)`, to make a regex pattern of `(c:\folder1|c:\folder2|c:\folder3|...)`.  Otherwise it'll probably need an inner loop over the contents of `$colExclusion`. (This is a comment not an answer because I don't want to put something together to test it)

Comment: You are correct. I posted an answer to my own question with the code that worked using your idea. This is my first question, so hopefully that is the correct way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TesselatingHeckler was right.**

I can create the expression on the fly, and the following is working. I did need to escape all the slashes in the list of directories though.

```
$colSelection = get-content "c:\scripts\selection.txt"
#$colExclusion = get-content "c:\scripts\exclusion.txt"
$colExclusion = "($((get-content "c:\scripts\exclusion.txt") -join '|' ))"
foreach ($folder in $colSelection) {
    $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $folder -recurse -force | where-object {$_.FullName -notmatch $colExclusion})
    foreach ($item in $colItems) {
        Add-Content -Path c:\scripts\testlist.txt -Value $item.FullName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `Get-Content` by default returns a collection (or an *array*, if you will) of strings, you're comparing the `$_.FullName` string to a collection of strings.

You can look at the parent directory against the entire array with `-notcontains`:

```
$childItems = Get-ChildItem $folder -Recurse -Force 
$childItems | Where-Object {$colExclusion -notcontains $_.Directory.FullName -and (-not $_.PSIsContainer)}
```

or you can compare each item in the `$colItems` to the beginning of each path with a `ForEach-Object` call inside the `Where-Object` filter:

```
$childItems | Where-Object {$(
    $path = $_.FullName
    $colItems | ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -notlike "$path*"){ return $true }
    }
)}
```

Comment: But the `$_.FullName` will include a filename, and the `$colExclusions` is a list of folders, it will never contain the FullName. The check needs to be a partial match check of the beginning of the file path.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Spot on, thanks for pointing it out. Added suggestion for partial matching against start of string

Comment: `$colExclusion -notcontains $_.Directory.FullName` is still risky; if the file is `c:\data\music\artists\group\1.mp3` and the exclusion is `c:\data\music` then the file will wrongly be included. I think the only way is to do a substring match (or maybe to do something with the get-childitem -exclude property to avoid going into those folders at all?)